# Is it possible to load Socket.IO from an external source?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Im looking for a library that don't requires to be installed e.g it's API listed from an external source, like jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

</body>
</html>

<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case it's Socket.IO, but the problem here is that I need install Socket.IO. I don't want to do that. I just want to load its javascripts from an external source as above.

So my questions are:

1. Can Sockets.IO be loaded from an external source without being installed? If yes, from where? Who is hosting a reliable source?
2. If the anser is no on question 1. Is there another Socket library that can be done that way?

Comment: Sure. It why? What do want to gain

Comment: @DanielA.White A reliable source like Google or Socket.IO Dev team etc.

Comment: I mean what benefit would that give you? Cdn delivery has kinda gone out of style

Comment: @DanielA.White Im going to implement a webbserver with only 128 kB ram. I need something that can handle sockets and is very small. So my idea is to load sockets from an external source. But which one?

Comment: That’s  a whole nother can of worms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `<script>` tag to load Socket.io from a CDN:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-/KNQL8Nu5gCHLqwqfQjA689Hhoqgi2S84SNUxC3roTe4EhJ9AfLkp8QiQcU8AMzI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

(Code snippet was borrowed from https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/#from-a-cdn)